# How can I return a new array based on a search criteria?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out how can I develop a search box.

I have this array `passengersData` which is coming from a redux store.

All of the examples about search functionality on React I've seen are based on local state with the search input in the same component where the rendered data array lives. But I need to pass the value of the search box to the child component, and then, what can I do to perform the search?

This is the child component:

```
// imports

const PassengerCardBasedOnRoute = ({
  passengersData,
  searchParam,
}) => {
  return (
      <View>
        {passengersData &&
           passengersData.map(info => (
            <PassengersInfo
              key={info.id}
              searchParam={searchParam}
              name={info.name}
              callModal={popupsModalsActionHandler}
            />
          ))}
      </View>
  );
};

// Props validatiom

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      passengersData: store.homeScreen.passengersData,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      popupsModalsActionHandler: data => {
        dispatch(popupsModalsAction(data));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(PassengerCardBasedOnRoute);
```

And this is the component that will hold the search box:

```
// imports
// CHILD COMPONENT
import PassengerCardBasedOnRoute from '../PassengerInfo/PassengerCardBasedOnRoute';

class AllPassengersList extends Component {
  state = { searchParam: '' };

  render() {
    const { searchParam } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        {isVisible && (
          <View>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ searchParam: text })}
              value={searchParam}
            />
          </View>
        )}
        <PassengerCardBasedOnRoute searchParam={searchParam} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// Props validation

export default compose(
  connect(store => ({
    navigationStore: store.homeScreen.navigation,
    passengersData: store.homeScreen.passengersData,
  })),
)(AllPassengersList);
```

So, based on my code, how can I grab the value and what should I do to perform the search across `passengersData` array?

Also, as you may see, `passengersData` is coming from a redux store.

Comment: It already looks like you are sending the search param as a prop to your child component. What's the problem? Question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Hi @MattWay yeah sorry I will change the title of my question but what I need to know is what I should do perform the search. Should I set a new array on a state with the search param? Like how do I perform the search with that search param I am sending to the child component.

Comment: Not really sure. What does `passengersData` look like? Are you trying to filter the data where you are currently performing `map()`?

Comment: `passengersData` is just an array of objects. And yes, the idea is to filter the data where I am using the `map()` method. @MattWay

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you can do to achieve what you want. The first is to simply augment your `map` to also include a filter. For example:

```
{passengersData && passengersData
 .filter(info => {
   // return true here if info matches the searchParam
 })
 .map(info => ( ...
```

The other is to move your search params from local state to redux, and perform the filter inside an action that responds to the search param being changed. For simplicity I would go with the first option for now, but if it turns out you need to access the search param in other parts of your app, or do something more complex (like optimise rendering or something), I would move the search stuff into redux.

Comment: Yeah. Now it is filtering the data with the `filter` method applied but it doesn't return anything unless I put the exact input. For example, the objects in the array contains the `name` key. So: `name: Mark Castle` if I want to obtain that item, I have to write `Mark Castle`, if I enter `mark` it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Write your filter such that it matches partial and ignores case, i.e. `filter(info => { return info.toLowerCase().includes(searchParam.toLowerCase()) })`

Comment: I did with Redux. But now I have a new question. Maybe you could help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818413/what-is-the-proper-way-to-implement-a-search-functionality-using-react-redux